# SQL Server 2005 Using DateAdd to add a day to a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, dateadd

How do I in SQL Server 2005 use the DateAdd function to add a day to a date

Answer (score 125):

Use the following function:

```
DATEADD(type, value, date)
```

- **date** is the date you want to manipulate
- **value** is the integere value you want to add (or subtract if you provide a negative number)
- **type** is one of:
- yy, yyyy: year
- qq, q: quarter
- mm, m: month
- dy, y: day of year
- dd, d: day
- wk, ww: week
- dw, w: weekday
- hh: hour
- mi, n: minute
- ss or s: second
- ms: millisecond
- mcs: microsecond
- ns: nanosecond

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, GETDATE()) -- will return a current date + 1 day
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Comment: I think you want to use GETDATE() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of NOW()

Answer (score 23):

```
DECLARE @MyDate datetime

-- ... set your datetime's initial value ...'

DATEADD(d, 1, @MyDate)
```

Answer (score 13):

Try following code will Add one day to current date

```
select DateAdd(day, 1, GetDate())
```

And in the same way can use Year, Month, Hour, Second etc. instead of day in the same function

Answer (score 9):

The following query I have used in SQL Server 2008, it may be help you.

For add day

```
DATEADD(DAY,20,GETDATE())
```

*20 is the day quantity

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @date DateTime
SET @date = GetDate()
SET @date = DateAdd(day, 1, @date)

SELECT @date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select getdate() -- 2010-02-05 10:03:44.527

-- To get all date format
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),100) +' '+ 'Date -100- MMM DD YYYY' -- Feb 5 2010
union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),101) +' '+ 'Date -101- MM/DDYYYY'
Union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),102) +' '+ 'Date -102- YYYY.MM.DD'
Union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),103) +' '+ 'Date -103- DD/MM/YYYY'
Union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),104) +' '+ 'Date -104- DD.MM.YYYY'
Union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),105) +' '+ 'Date -105- DD-MM-YYYY'
Union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),getdate(),106) +' '+ 'Date -106- DD MMM YYYY' --ex: 03 Jan 2007
Union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),107) +' '+ 'Date -107- MMM DD,YYYY' --ex: Jan 03, 2007
union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),109) +' '+ 'Date -108- MMM DD YYYY' -- Feb 5 2010
union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),110) +' '+ 'Date -110- MM-DD-YYYY' --02-05-2010
union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),getdate(),111) +' '+ 'Date -111- YYYY/MM/DD'
union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),112) +' '+ 'Date -112- YYYYMMDD' -- 20100205
union
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),113) +' '+ 'Date -113- DD MMM YYYY' -- 05 Feb 2010


SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 20) -- 2010-02-05 10:25:14
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 23) -- 2010-02-05
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 24) -- 10:24:20
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 25) -- 2010-02-05 10:24:34.913
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 21) -- 2010-02-05 10:25:02.990


---==================================
-- To get the time
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),108) +' '+ 'Date -108- HH:MM:SS' -- 10:05:53

select CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),getdate(),114) +' '+ 'Date -114- HH:MM:SS:MS' -- 10:09:46:223
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 22) -- 02/05/10 10:23:11 AM
----=============================================
SELECT getdate()+1
SELECT month(getdate())+1
SELECT year(getdate())+1
```

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question.