# How to update column in SQL Server 30 days from stored date on form load?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to take the rows with a `createDate` 30 days old and change the bit value `IsExpired` to `1`. How do I accomplish this?

Here is the query I have tried:

```
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] 
SET IsExpired = 1 
WHERE CreateDate > (time, SYSDATETIME(GETDATE(CreateDate)+30))
```

The `CreateDate` column has a `datetime` string stored within it from a C# project. For example the value stored in the first row is `2013-05-29 14:59:48.000`. When I execute it in SQL I get an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Is this SQL or C#.NET. This looks like SQL. This issue is what is (time, XXX)

Comment: if its sql try UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] SET IsExpired=1 WHERE CreateDate > dateadd(dd, 30, getdate())

Comment: I am testing a query in SQLServer that I want to use in C#

Comment: i get `0 rows affected` is this because `IsExpired` is a bit datatype? should I use int instead?

Comment: my bad... it needs to go back 30 days

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] 
SET IsExpired = 1 
WHERE CreateDate < dateadd(dd, -30, getdate())
```

Comment: i get `0 rows affected` is this because `IsExpired` is a bit datatype? should I use int instead?

Answer (score 2):

Try below Query:

```
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] SET IsExpired=1 WHERE CreateDate < DATEADD(dd, -30, GETDATE())
```

Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/167539/1671639) will help you to know about DATEADD().

First I assumed that Skullomania is trying to get 30 days of CreateDate.  Later from Scott Chamberlain comments, I got the point of user.

Comment: You are comparing it with itself, should one of those `CreateDate`s be a `GetDate()`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I thought Skullomania is comparing with CreateDate -30 day from CreateDate.

Comment: I think Skullomania had no idea what he was doing and made a guess on what to do, that guess was wrong and he came here to find out the correct way to do it. The use of [`SYSDATETIME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630353.aspx) makes me think he really just wanted to use `GetDate()` with a `DateAdd()`, If you logiclly step through the code you gave him you just said `Where 1=1 and CreateDate is not null` as a date minus 30 days will always be less than the original date (unless it is null)!

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for insight of the question.

Answer (score 2):

The following should match where the **CreateDate** field is less than 30 days prior to the current date of your SQL server. You may want to use **GETUTCDATE()** if you store your times in UTC.

```
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] SET IsExpired=1 
    WHERE CreateDate < DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
UPDATE [mydb].[dbo].[mytable] 
SET IsExpired=1 
WHERE CreateDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```