# SQL add one day to start date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following `select` statement that display the start date to end date information. I would like to add one day to the "start date". That means instead of 27/10/2016. It will be come 28/10/2016.

```
CONCAT(FORMAT(sc.StartDate,'dd/MM/yyy'), + ' - ' + FORMAT(sc.ENDDate,'dd/MM/yyy')) SIPDate
```

I'm using SQL server 2014.

Comment: Refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167491/sql-server-2005-using-dateadd-to-add-a-day-to-a-date

Comment: Look at dateadd. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `DATEADD` function:

```
CONCAT(FORMAT(DATEADD(dd,1,sc.StartDate),'dd/MM/yyy'), + ' - ' + FORMAT(sc.ENDDate,'dd/MM/yyy')) SIPDate
```

MSDN reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATEADD()` function.
Example:

```
DATEADD(day,1,StartDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dateadd`

```
Dateadd(dd,1,Startdate) as Startdate
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use **GETDATE()** Also

if your start date is today:

```
select DATEADD(day,1,GETDATE())
```

[image: image1]

```
 select convert (varchar, dateadd(DAY,1,getdate()),103)
```

[image: image2]

For specific date use this:

```
  declare @date as date ='20161027'
  select convert (varchar, dateadd(DAY,+1,@date),103)
```

[image: image3]