# How to convert the sequential number into date format using SQL/Python?

Tags: python, sql, date, pyspark, hiveql

In the retail dataset(CSV), I have a column "Day" and it has value starting from 1 to 712 (around two years of data). I want to convert it into a "yyyy-MM-dd" format. The starting timestamp is 2017-01-01.

```
ACTUAL:

Day, Prod_id, Sales
1, 23232, 34.5
1, 34522, 76
2, 53436, 45.7
2, 67353, 12.5
.....
.....
712, 35357, 67.2

EXPECTED:

Day, Prod_id, Sales, TS
1, 23232, 34.5, 2017-01-01
1, 34522, 76, 2017-01-01
2, 53436, 45.7, 2017-01-02
2, 67353, 12.5, 2017-01-02
.....
.....
712, 35357, 67.2, 2018-12-25
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server 2005 Using DateAdd to add a day to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167491/sql-server-2005-using-dateadd-to-add-a-day-to-a-date)

Comment: Marked as duplicate, you can use the DateAdd function to add $day-1 days onto 2017-01-01

Comment: similar to what @Lamanus pointed, `df.withColumn("TS",F.to_date(F.lit("2017-01-01"))).withColumn("TS1",F.expr("date_add(TS,Day)"))` make sure to subtract 1 from Day column first, this would work as per each row Day value

Comment: Thanks, everyone. The below hive query solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Hive use `date_add('2017-01-01', day) as ts`